# CharSequence to Integer with multiple +ve and -ve signss

Tags: java, android, charsequence

i have learned that to convert charsequence to integer we can use this statement

```
String cs="123";    
int number = Integer.parseInt(cs.toString());
```

what if

```
cs = "++-+--25";
```

will this statement still run and give answer -25 according to string given??

Comment: I don't think this will convert to integer, you will end up with number format exception.

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: 2 upvotes?  What is StackOverflow becoming?

Comment: yup. exception. any solution to get the desired result? 

(in this case -25)

Comment: You haven't explained why it should be -ve, so how can someone give a solution?  Normally, +ve and -ve cancel each other out so I would expect "++-+--25" to be +25.  Trying things out yourself is far more effective than using StackOverlow for these simple problems plus, you learn a lot more.

Comment: when signs are written like this they are meant to be multiplied which equals -25 not +25.

Answer (score 2):

You are end up with a `NumberFormatException`  since `++-+--25`  is not a valid integer.

See the [docs of parseInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)

> Parses the string argument as a signed decimal integer. **The characters in the string must all be decimal digits, except that the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a negative value or an ASCII plus sign '+' ('\u002B') to indicate a positive value.** The resulting integer value is returned, exactly as if the argument and the radix 10 were given as arguments to the parseInt(java.lang.String, int) method.

So you are allowed to do

```
CharSequence cs = "-25"; //gives you -25
```

and

```
CharSequence cs = "+25";   //gives you 25
```

Otherwise ,take necessary steps to face the `Exception` :)

So know the char Sequence is a valid string just write a simple method to return true or false and then proceed further

```
public static boolean  {
    try { 
        Integer.parseInt(s); 
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) { 
        return false;  // no boss you entered a wrong format
    }

    return true; //valid integer
}
```

Then your code looks like

```
if(isInteger(cs.toString())){
int number = Integer.parseInt(cs.toString());
// proceed remaining
}else{
// No, Operation cannot be completed.Give proper input.
}
```

Comment: right. isnt there any other way that it automatically detects whether the number is positive or negative? using smother builtin function?

Comment: @Muneeb You mean you want to check weather the char sequence a valid string or not before parsing ??

Comment: actually i m trying to make a calculator and trying to seprate first number 
e.g 
++-+--25/-2    (in this case seprating ++-+--25 so that making it error free as it is legal statement accord to maths)
now 1 method is i go through all signs and then save resultant and second if any builtinfunction could do it so i have "-25" as an integer

Comment: @Muneeb added a small util method do your job, use that method before doing your operations to check :) Hope that helps. If you still needs clarification, let me know

Comment: but the expression is true. i dont want it to make an exception. do it urself on simple calculator it will solve such expression... i have seprated first number so now

cs= "++-+--25" now is there any builtin function tht can give me -25 in integer or do i must have to go through loop in cs to determine what will the sign be?cause user can also enter "+++--25" which in that case answer be +25... :S

Comment: AFAIK,No.There is no direct function, you have to use the above check and then proceed. Even any library is providing I bet they use like above :). You are ot making/printing exception. You just checking that could be parsable or not because we won't trust the users, we only trust java :P

Comment: hmm. still i have to implement same method in else if there are more than 1 signs. this is useful in case if cs variable just having one sign. +ve or -ve. then i have no choice i will have to determine final sign by my self after going through cs variable. thanks for helping me out :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39622/discussion-between-ss--and-muneeb)

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your question is code will run and throw Exception as "++-+--25" is not a valid int,

```
   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "++-+--25"
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "++-+--25"
```

*Tested example :*

```
CharSequence cs = "++-+--25";
System.out.println("" + Integer.parseInt(cs.toString()));
```