# Hex to binary conversion java

Tags: java, binary, hex

I have the following code

```
temp = "0x00"
String binAddr = Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.parseInt(temp, 16));
```

Why do I get the following error:

`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0x00"`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19488067/charsequence-to-integer-with-multiple-ve-and-ve-signss/19488112#19488112

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the string contains `0x`, use [Integer.decode(String nm)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#decode%28java.lang.String%29):

```
String binAddr = Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.decode(temp));
```

Comment: This gives me again..Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0x00"

Comment: String binAddr = Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.decode(temp)); again error...string temp is "0x00"

Comment: @user2761225 That's working fine in my case. Check it again, you might be doing something wrong somewhere else.

Comment: Working for me too: double check that your string is ``0x00``.

Comment: u were right.. i have forgotten something else inside the loop ..it's working thnx guys

Comment: these produces for example 00000001? or 1? if i want 8bit?? i mean 0x00 = 00000000??

Answer (score 0):

Because the leading `0x` is not part of a valid base-16 number -- it's just a convention to indicate to a reader that a number is in hex.

Comment: so if i make substring without first two is ok?

Comment: Yes -- read [the Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.htm)

Comment: do u know how to get 8-bit binary conversion i mean that 0x00 is 00000000 not 0??

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the '0x': from the javadocs:

> The characters in the string must all be digits of the specified radix (as determined by whether Character.digit(char, int) returns a nonnegative value), except that the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a negative value or an ASCII plus sign '+' ('\u002B') to indicate a positive value. The resulting integer value is returned.

Answer (score 0):

BigInteger.toString(radix) will solve this issue

Refer [method description](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toString%28int%29)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The `0x` is for integer *literals*, eg:

```
int num = 0xCAFEBABE;
```

but is not a parseable format. Try this:

```
temp = "ABFAB"; // without the "0x"
String binAddr = Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.parseInt(temp, 16));
```